# Keycloak failed to update database

Tags: docker, keycloak, liquibase

Good day folks,

I've been trying to solve this problem I encountered keycloak. I run it in my docker on ubuntu 18 and ubuntu 20. my docker compose was okay... I have mysql and keycloak services on my docker compose. The credentials of the database were also double checked.

I'm using mysql 5.7 and keycloak 15.0.0 (i also tried in lates keycloak docker image but failed)

I keep getting this error:

```
04:46:08,599 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Change Set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com failed.  Error: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE keycloak.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]
04:46:08,599 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Error has occurred while updating the database: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:
```

I wonder what went wrong. I already done the same steps I used to install production env.

I need help. Thanks!!!

I tried having mysql docker and mysql on the server but failed. I checked the privileges on the user i created in mysql but doesn't help.

Comment: The error message says that the table already exist, so nothing is wrong with dtabase permissions. You should take rhe issue up with keycloak. Not sure what you expext us to do from a programming point of view here.

Comment: Thank you. We figured out that it was the KEYCLOAK_IMPORT. We had to add the existing json file and it works.